# Opencart related option

Tags: module, opencart, extension-methods, opencart2.x

I'm a newbie to opencart. Here I'm using opencart 2.1.0.2 for my E-Commerce website by customizing this theme (http://demo.towerthemes.com/tt_goetze/). In our website we have options in product page by which customer can choose color and size of the product as per their wish. We have options in back-end by which I already added those size and color option in website which is independent. In that we can add quantity of that product independently. Like for color red-quantity 10,color white-quantity 10. Almost site is completed. But now what my client need is, he want to add quantity of the product based on both of those options. Like in red color-Large size quantity 10, in white color- small size quantity 11.

After long try I moved on to check extension. I purchased Dependent / Related Options OC2 extension(https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=22909&filter_search=dependant%20options) but it not at all working. Anyone please help me sort out this problem. Any other free extension are there to solve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is not dependent options but options with stock levels, so have a look at this forum post:
https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=127414

And extensions like these:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=18773 and
https://shop.welfordmedia.co.uk/openstock-2

There are a few others also - search the store for "option stock":
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=option%20stock

Comment: The extension which I purchased was working well in default theme. But I installed another theme. Is there nay option to maintain two themes in same website

Comment: You will probably need the extension developer to make it work with your theme.